# VBA Access - Outlook cannot find name assigning a task through Access

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I have successfully written code to create a task in Outlook. I used the code below in Private Sub OutlookTask_Click() define the recipient and it worked fine as well. However, I needed to add some custom field in my Outlook Task form. I changed the code to what is listed in Private Sub test1_Click(). It works fine assigning the task to myself using .save. When I am assigning to someone else I get the error outlook cannot find the name. The answer posted worked fine, Just needed to change MyItem to OlTask.

```
Private Sub OutlookTask_Click()
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OlTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim OlTaskProp As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim OlLocation As Object
Dim OlDelegate As Outlook.Recipient
Dim TName As String


Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlTask = OlApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Set OlTaskProp = OlLocation.UserProperties.Find("Mlocation")
TName = Me.Alias
'Set OlDelegate = OlTask.Recipients.Add(TName)

With OLTask
    .Subject = Me.Item
    .StartDate = Me.Start_Date
    .DueDate = Me.Due_Date
    .Status = TStatus
    .Importance = TPriority
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderTime = Me.Due_Date - 3 & " 8:00AM"
    .Body = Me.Description
    .UserProperties("MLocation") = Me.Location


If Me.Alias = "Troy" Then
          .Save
        Else
         .Assign
         Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient
         Set myDelegate = OlTask.Recipients.Add(TName)
         myDelegate.Resolve
    End If

    If myDelegate.Resolved Then
        .Send
    Else
        MsgBox "Name not Found"

    End If
MsgBox "Task Successful"
End Sub



Private Sub test1_Click()

Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim OLTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim OlItems As Outlook.Items
Dim OlDelegate As Outlook.Recipient
Dim TName As String
Dim TStatus As Integer
Dim TPriority As Integer

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objFolder = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
Set OlItems = objFolder.Items
Set OLTask = OlItems.Add("IPM.Task.TroyTask")
TName = Me.Alias
Set OlDelegate = OLTask.Recipients.Add(TName)


With OLTask
    .Subject = Me.Item
    .StartDate = Me.Start_Date
    .DueDate = Me.Due_Date
    .Status = TStatus
    .Importance = TPriority
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderTime = Me.Due_Date - 3 & " 8:00AM"
    .Body = Me.Description
    .UserProperties("MLocation") = Me.Location


If Me.Alias = "Troy" Then
    .Save
    Else
        .Assign
        .Send
    End If
End With
MsgBox "Task Successful"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be submitting delegated task without sufficient preparation of its internal structures because `Assign()` is immediately followed by `Send()`:

```vb
If Me.Alias = "Troy" Then
    .Save
Else
    .Assign
    .Send   ' problem
End If
```

In this case, recipients need to be resolved. See resolving of a task delegate's name visible in the working [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem.assign). I adopted it without testing here:

```vb
If Me.Alias = "Troy" Then
    .Save
Else
    .Assign
    Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient             'added
    Set myDelegate = OlTask.Recipients.Add(TName)   'added
    myDelegate.Resolve                              'added
    If myDelegate.Resolved Then                     'added
        .Send
    Else                                            'added
        'report error here                          'added
    End If                                          'added
End If
```

The `Resolve()` call can be earlier in your code, this was just an illustration taken from the example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried everything but the resolve piece. Strange the error now is the same as before  "cannot find recipient" but it is happening on .Send as if it is resolved. There seems to be something related to the MAPI folder and pointing to OlTasks folder.

Comment: @TroyL – maybe you can update your question with the new code visible for others to help you

Comment: Hello Again, When editing my post, I noticed I had not changed MyItem to OlTask. Made that change and it works. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @TroyL – I have fixed the code, too. Good to see that the culprit with missing Recipients and resolving was found. If the above was the actual answer, maybe you can consider marking it as accepted as shown in the [tour].